# How functional is DbContext as an ObjectContext provider?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, .net-4.0

We have a large EF 4.0 data framework (based on `ObjectContext`, `EntitySet`, `EntityObject` and `ObjectStateManager`) which was developed with DB-first in mind. Given that one can obtain an `ObjectContext` from a `DbContext`, could we use our existing framework with a code-first `DbContext` just by using `IObjectContextAdapter`?

I know that `DbContext` uses POCOs (and not `EntityObject` descendants), but those POCOs are internally proxy objects of type `Proxy<TPOCO>`. Do those proxies inherit or provide access to underlying `EntityObject` and is there an underlying `EntityObject` at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use `DbContext` by casting to `IObjectContextAdapter` and accessing `ObjectContext` where needed.

`DbContext` itself is happy with any class, you can use POCOs without Entity Framework creating proxies. If you use proxy objects, it's just objects derived from your POCO objects. Nothing more, nothing else. Hence there's no `EntityObject`.

Comment: Sorry I didn't fully understand your answer, are you saying that as long as I don't rely on the existence of EntityObject descendants in the context (for example the result of `GetObjectByKey`) I can use DbContext instead of an ObjectContext via the adapter interface?

Comment: @BorisB. `GetObjectByKey` returns an `object`, not an `EntityObject`, and will work just fine. You just need to make sure you don't attempt to cast the result to `EntityObject`.